# Change Indictor Settings & Read Indicator Values via API

Tags: tradingview-api, trading

I currently have an indicator on trading view with various inputs (a lot of them) and various outputs (a custom table + plotting).

I currently tweak the indicator input via the UI and see the effect it has on the outputs.

This is really cumbersome given the amount of inputs I have + the ranges of these inputs.

Is it possible to instead changes the inputs + read the resultant output via the TV API? My searches on Google didn't come out with anything too useful, unfortunately.